# Select the distinct latest records based on their creation date

Tags: php, sql, laravel, database, eloquent

How can I select, preferably using eloquent laravel's query builder, the latest distinct records from a table.

I have tried this query without success.

```
 Products::where('depart_id', $depart_id)
                ->distinct("serial_number")
                ->latest()
                ->where('serial_number', ""); // get one of the distinct products
```

Comment: `latest()` method sort records according to column `created_at`.

Comment: what type of error you facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use

```
 Products::where('depart_id', $depart_id)
                ->distinct('serial_number')
                ->orderBy('serial_number', 'desc')
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                ->where('serial_number', "serial_number");
```

This ensured that the distinct returned only the unique latest record of each value.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: `distinct()` will get the distinct `'serial_number'`

```
Products::where('depart_id', $depart_id) 
            ->where('serial_number', "")
            ->distinct();
```